# How to create .Rproj inside of a folder where an R package/project lives?

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, r-package

So I have an R package/project inside of a folder. This package/project was created without the .Rproj file.

How do I retroactively go back to create that file for that package/project?

Comment: If you're in RStudio, when you create a new project you have the option of creating it in a directory that already exists. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @camille I am using RStudio. But I am not trying to create a new project. The project already exists. But it doesn't have the .Rproj file. I want to create it.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't think creating a project in RStudio does much besides making an .Rproj file. I just tested it by making a folder with a couple files in it, then creating a new project inside that folder in RStudio. Doesn't seem to have done anything besides adding an .Rproj, which is itself just a text file

Answer (score 1):

The comment of [camille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5325862/camille) is the correct answer of your question.

If you're in RStudio, when you go to menu 'File | New Project' you have the option of creating the RStudio `*.Rproj` file in a directory/package that already exists.

[image: RStudio | Create Project | Existing Directory]

Answer (score 1):

From inside the project root, you can use:

```
usethis::create_project(".", rstudio = TRUE)
```

That converts your directory into an RStudio project, see the [usethis docs](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/create_package.html)

I often have to do this from the linux command line. If the repo I'm in doesn't have an *.Rproj then it can't easily be opened from the command line using `rstudio` (if RStudio is already open for another project, then that copy of RStudio will come to the foreground). Whereas if there is an .RProj, I can do `rstudio ./theProject.Rproj &` to open RStudio for that project (and any previously opened copies of RStudio remain open in the background).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best that you can do is creating new project, save it to the folder where you saved your files. When you click the Rproj that has been created, it will pull all the files associated with it.